# How to remove intercept from BMA in R

Tags: r, intercept

Is there a possibility to remove the intercept from BMA in R (BMA package). I tried it by replacing 'y~x' by 'y~0+x’ (like in glm), but it has no effect. Please what can I do to overcome this?

My test data:

```
x <- rbind(c(0, 0, 0),c(0, 1, 0),c(1, 0, 0),c(1, 1, 1))
colnames(x) <- c("x1","x2","x3")
y <- c(1,1,1,0)
d <- as.data.frame(cbind(y,x),stringsAsFActors=F)
```

The command

```
library(BMA)
bic.glm(y~0+x,data=d,glm.family=binomial(logit))
```

generates the output (with intercept)

```
Call:
bic.glm.formula(f = y ~ 0 + x, data = d, glm.family = binomial(logit))


 Posterior probabilities(%): 
 xx1  xx2  xx3 
43.3 43.3 65.0 

 Coefficient posterior expected values: 
(Intercept)          xx1          xx2          xx3  
     28.338       -8.163       -8.163      -30.641  
Warnmeldung:
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

But I need BMA without intercept!